# readlines gives me additional linebreaks python2.6.5

Tags: python, file, line, break, readlines

I have problems with the following code:

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
print lines[0]
print lines[1]
print lines[2]
file.close()
```

This code gives me linebreaks between the lines. So the output is something like this:

```
line0

line1

line2
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: print lines[0].strip()

Comment: try `lines[0].strip()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` *adds* a newline. Strip the newline from the line:

```
print lines[0].rstrip('\n')
print lines[1].rstrip('\n')
print lines[2].rstrip('\n')
```

If you are reading the whole file into a list *anyway*, an alternative would be to use [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
lines = file.read().splitlines()
```

which by default removes the newlines from the lines at the same time.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. This was new to me. What is the difference between strip and rstrip since both works for me?

Comment: @user3402107 Why dont you just read the docs ([rstrip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) and [strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip))

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm new to Python and the Python community. And obviously I'm not working good enough with the documentation yet. (;

Answer (score 0):

Do `strip` after each line. File has new line as last character. You have to remove it when you read it.

```
print line[index].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` will return an array of lines. Every line ends up with a line break.

If you want to print all lines in a block, simply do this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    print "".join(lines)
```

Use `with`, you can ever save a `file.close()`